# Getting Error 524 while running jupyter lab in google cloud platform

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, data-science, jupyter-lab

I am not able to access jupyter lab created on google cloud
[image]

I created one notebook using Google AI platform. I was able to start it and work but suddenly it stopped and I am not able to start it now. I tried building and restarting the jupyterlab, but of no use. I have checked my disk usages as well, which is only 12%.

I tried the diagnostic tool, which gave the following result:
[image]

but didn't fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that the problem persists even after creating a new JupyterLab instance? If you are just restarting the existing instance, how are you doing it? If you are restarting just the kernel, then can you please try stopping and starting the VM instance from the Notebook instance page as suggested [here](https://cloud.google.com/notebooks/docs/troubleshooting?hl=ja#jupyter-api_status_failure)?

Comment: yes, the problem existed even after restarting the VM instance multiple times.

Comment: Can you check the log? you can easily check it  by clicking <your instance name> on user-managed notebook tab and then clicking log tab. In my case, I found `ImportError: The Jupyter Server requires tornado >=6.1.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error might be caused by a corrupted disk partition “/dev/sdb”. After connecting to the notebook instance through SSH, run `sudo fsck /dev/sdb` to perform a disk check and repair, and then perform a reboot.

In case this does not help, you can download your data after zipping the required content from the “/home/jupyter/” folder and upload it to a new notebook instance.

Below is the zip utility command for your reference.

`cd /home/`

`sudo zip -r test-1.zip jupyter/`

Comment: You can access the instance via ssh with this link:
https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances

Answer (score 0):

For me I faced this issue When storage was full after increasing it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that your machine on which jupyter lab is hosted becomes unresponsive. This could be due to many reasons some of which include the notebook causing an out of memory at the OS level, or running something very heavy which causes heavy load on the disk or the CPU.

A quick fix would be to just restart the machine/Vertex AI notebook.

Answer (score -1):

You should try this Google Notebook trouble shooting section about 524 errors : https://cloud.google.com/notebooks/docs/troubleshooting?hl=ja#opening_a_notebook_results_in_a_524_a_timeout_occurred_error

Comment: I tried the diagnostic tool, it says jupyter api is not active but not able to fix it.