# Jupyter internal API is not active - Vertex-AI jupyterlab error 524

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter, jupyter-lab, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I cannot access Jupyterlab by web interface (error 524). It still works by ssh. I've followed the support documentations, but nothing works.

My best guess is that the main issue is with the opened ports of docker.
The key problem is probably below:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/kernelspecs
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused
```

And the following command simply restarts the service without error (but still inaccessible through web interface)

```
sudo service jupyter restart
```

Thanks!

EDIT: to clarify, all help from [this article](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/troubleshooting-workbench#opening_a_notebook_results_in_a_524_a_timeout_occurred_error_2) which specifically is supposed to fix error 524, doesn't work at all.
The diagnostic tool give this result, and the `--repair` doesn't work:

[image: diagnostic tool]

And ["Verify that the Jupyter internal API is active"](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/troubleshooting-workbench#verify_that_the_jupyter_internal_api_is_active) is completely useless as it doesn't explain how to fix the error!!

So I know there is a problem with the **Jupyter internal API** but no idea how to fix that.

EDIT 2:
On the web console, here is a screenshot:
[image: console gcp]

Comment: Does this [article](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/troubleshooting#opening_a_notebook_results_in_a_524_a_timeout_occurred_error_2) by Google helps you to solve your problem.Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi @kiranmathew, just edited the post to give specifics about the help article, in short it doesn't explain how to fix "Jupyter internal API" problem

Comment: Found some similar [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68862621/getting-error-524-while-running-jupyter-lab-in-google-cloud-platform) , [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72445868/524-error-and-jupyterlab-api-status-unhealthy). Does that help you to solve your problem? .For a workaround , I would suggest trying to create a new VM instance instead (you can backup instance).

Comment: thanks, i've already tried both suggested help on those threads and doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through the same error, after upgrading the VM problem got solved all the Jupyter API are healthy try upgrading the VM. Before that take a snapshot of disk(upgrading might erase your VM).
[How to upgrade the VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMFJn.png)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment a work around to resolve the issue can be by create a new instance keeping the old data.For this you can follow below steps:

`Step 1:`  Create a new storage bucket and a new notebook.

`Step 2:`  Copy the data to the newly created bucket by running the following command in the old notebook terminal.

```
 "gsutil cp -R /home/jupyter/* gs://NEW_STORAGE_BUCKET_PATH"
```

`Step 3:`  From the new managed notebook’s terminal, run the below command to copy the data to this new notebook .

```
"gsutil cp gs://NEW_STORAGE_BUCKET_PATH* /home/jupyter/"
```